# While loop for multiple files as inputs

Tags: bash

i am really new to coding and trying to get this while loop to read lines from files.

i am using below code to make curl call to a URL

```
while IFS= read -r -u 3 line && IFS= read -r -u 4 line1;
do
           curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $line" -X GET $url$line1 > output.txt

done 3< $file1 4< $file2
```

passing the two lines from different files.
one file has only 1 line and the other has few lines.

when i run the script it runs but only reads one line from file2

Comment: Please post code with proper formatting, wrap the code in a '```' block by putting 3 backticks at the start and the end. And also provide some sample data

Comment: What is the purpose of the `&&` in your code? How do you think it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can use use direct redirection of text and create this text using "cat" command which accept multiple files:

```
while IFS= read -r -u 3 line && IFS= read -r -u 4 line1;
do
           curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $line" -X GET $url$line1 > output.txt

done <<< $(cat $file1 $file2)
```

Comment: HI,
thanks for the reply, i tried your solution and it does work but on the line2 it reads both the lines from file2 that is line and line1

Comment: i ended up using a export method to achive what i needed. i called the file1 script other script and that worked for me, thanks for help